# Docker images built successfully but not running

Tags: docker

Hello I am creating a docker image and it's successful but when I run it's erroring out on app.jar which I am adding in build process. Any suggestions?

Docker file contents

```
FROM openjdk:alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD cta-details-service-1.0.0.jar app.jar
ADD start.sh start.sh
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
RUN bash -c 'chmod +x /start.sh'
EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]
```

Image build log:

```
$ docker build -t mpcs/ctl-details-service .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 89.71 MB
Step 1 : FROM openjdk:alpine
 ---> a7dc136ad22e
Step 2 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b8dcf8f9963
Step 3 : ADD cta-details-service-1.0.0.jar app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b9d84248d3ab
Step 4 : ADD start.sh start.sh
 ---> 05a56f93e41c
Removing intermediate container 72523c54524d
Step 5 : RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Running in b49b75c3d6f6
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.0-r7)
(2/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.0-r7)
(3/5) Installing ncurses-libs (6.0-r7)
(4/5) Installing readline (6.3.008-r4)
(5/5) Installing bash (4.3.42-r3)
Executing bash-4.3.42-r3.post-install
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r9.trigger
OK: 149 MiB in 40 packages
 ---> 5318da18a15d
Removing intermediate container b49b75c3d6f6
Step 6 : RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
 ---> Running in f914f0b2ecd2
 ---> e3aa35585f02
Removing intermediate container f914f0b2ecd2
Step 7 : RUN bash -c 'chmod +x /start.sh'
 ---> Running in 722749bbcc10
 ---> 647463ac0982
Removing intermediate container 722749bbcc10
Step 8 : EXPOSE 8090
 ---> Running in 7194e3b95ee6
 ---> c52f3648f921
Removing intermediate container 7194e3b95ee6
Step 9 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /start.sh
 ---> Running in 0d30553ed406
 ---> adede39132c8
Removing intermediate container 0d30553ed406
Successfully built adede39132c8
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Win
dows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-r
wxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions f
or sensitive files and directories.
```

Docker run errors:

```
$ docker run -p 8090:8090 -t mpcs/ctl-details-service
Error: Unable to access jarfile /app.jar
```

Folder content where I am running it from:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the `app.jar` file is being added where you expect? I'd try changing `ADD cta-details-service-1.0.0.jar app.jar` to `ADD cta-details-service-1.0.0.jar /app.jar` to ensure the file is where you want it to be. (and do the same with your start script)

Comment: As @Krysten wrote, it's most likely that your app.jar isn't at the right location.  Use this line to install/update Alpine components `apk --no-cache add bash`. No need to rm the cache this way..  Also Also, use COPY instead of ADD. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/add-or-copy

Comment: It turned out that the issue was with /bin/bash I changed it to bash and it started working. This was on docker toolbox on windows 7.